# Override element type in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, patternfly

I have two nested Patternfly 4 components, specifically `DualListSelector` that uses `TreeView` as its items. My problem is that both these contain `<button>` and I am seeing those

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.
```

errors in console. I was looking through the sources for these components but it seems I can't configure either places to use a different element type; is there any hack to override it?

(Note: I know that DualListSelector supports tree view natively, but the behaviour had some shortcomings in my use case that led me to do the tree view on my own.)